# Do a render foreach loop on a regular field?

Tags: entities

I have a regular field with multiple values,
If i do

```
render( $fields['field1'] )
```

It prints

```
Field1_value1
Field1_value2
Field1_value3
etc
```

Am trying to get it to output like this

```
[Field1_value1]
[Field1_value2]
[Field1_value3]
etc
```

To add `[` and `]` to the output.
I thought of using a foreach loop, but the field array is like such

```
'#title' => 'xxxx',
'#type' => 'xxxx',
...
'0' => <array>,
'1' => <array>,
'2' => <array>,
```

How can I get it to loop throught the `[0], [1], [2] etc` only?

Note: I have no control on how many multiple values the field may have, so I have to loop.

---

Another solution that worked well for me: [Display comma-separated list of taxonomy terms?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3926/display-comma-separated-list-of-taxonomy-terms)

You can make use of the power of field.tpl.php.

Answer (score 1):

```
$field_values = element_children($fields['field1']);
foreach($field_values as $field_value) { ... }
```

I was looking for the answer to this too, and ended up hunting through the `render()` function. It wasn't too far down the chain: `drupal_render()` calls [element_children()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/element_children/7).

> ### element_children
>
> Identifies the children of an element array, optionally sorted by weight.
>
> The children of a element array are those key/value pairs whose key does not start with a '#'. See [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try a regular expression loop after the print? See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

If you're really experiencing problems with the loop, check out the documentation for [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).