# Making terms as a list format

Tags: theming

This is my layout http://www.gorgeoushentai.com/content/saber-marionette-j-2
If you look at the genres section it shows them as a div class and I want it as a < li > . How can I make it a list format? I can't find where it's printing the terms in the templates. This is for drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template file you're looking for is [field.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--theme--field.tpl.php/). The naming suggestions for this template are explained fairly well [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--theme--field.tpl.php/7#comment-13339) and [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--theme--field.tpl.php/7#comment-15279) - although they aren't in the documentation and I haven't tested them. So the steps you need to take are:

1. Copy the .tpl.php file from *modules/field/theme*
2. Rename it so it
   targets only the field type you wan't ('list_text' I think in your
   case).
3. Change the `divs` into `ul`/`ol` and `li` as required.

Comment: @Ruriko [Display comma-separated list of taxonomy terms?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3926/display-comma-separated-list-of-taxonomy-terms/3939#3939) is similar and may help you get started. Simply change the DIV outside the `foreach` to a `<ul>` or `<ol>' and the DIVs inside the `foreach` to `<li>`'s