# Tags on one line

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Can somebody walk me through how to get my tags to appear on one line instead of like a list?
I could use a step-by-step list on how to change this.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Have you seen http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3926/display-comma-separated-list-of-taxonomy-terms?